# laravel dynamic dropdown with hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dynamic, drop-down-menu

how to show sub-category while selected category with hasMany relationship using javascript or jquery??

there my Parent Table

```
 public function ChildrenRasHewan() {
        return $this->hasMany(RasHewan::class,'jenis_hewan_id');
    }
```

and this is my Child table a.k.a sub category

```
 public function ParentJenisHewan() {
        return $this->belongsTo(JenisHewan::class,'jenis_hewan_id','id');
    }
```

this is what my controller look like :

```
  public function index()
    {
        $this->data['adopsi'] = Adopsi::paginate(10);
        return view('admin.dashboard.adopsi.index-adopsi', $this->data);
    }

  
    public function create()
    {
        $this->data['getStatusAdopsi'] = Adopsi::statusAdopsi();
        $this->data['jenisHewan'] = JenisHewan::pluck('nama_jenis_hewan');
        $this->data['rasHewan'] = JenisHewan::all();
        
        return view('admin.dashboard.adopsi.create-adopsi',$this->data);
    }

    public function getRasHewan($id) {
        $getRasHewan = DB::table('ras_hewans')->where('id',$id)->pluck('nama_ras_hewan','id');
        return json_encode($getRasHewan);
    }
```

this is my **index** view where i want to applied dynamic dropdown :

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="jenis_hewan_id">Jenis Hewan</label>
                                <select name="jenis_hewan_id" id="jenis_hewan_id" class="form-control @error('jenis_hewan_id') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="">
                                    <option value="">Pilih Jenis Hewan</option>
                                    @foreach ($jenisHewan as $data)
                                     <option value="{{$data->id}}" type="text">{{$data->nama_jenis_hewan}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ras_hewan_id">Ras Hewan</label>
                                <select name="ras_hewan_id" id="ras_hewan_id" class="form-control @error('ras_hewan_id') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="" >
                                    <option value="" selected disabled>Pilih Ras Hewan</option>
                                    @foreach ($jenisHewan as $data)
                                    @if($data->ChildrenRasHewan))
                                        @foreach ($data->ChildrenRasHewan as $rasHewan )
                                        <option value="{{$rasHewan->id}}">{{$rasHewan->nama_ras_hewan}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                 @endforeach
                                    <select name="ras_hewan_id" id="ras_hewan_id" class="form-control"></select>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

the js script :

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('select[name=service_id]').change(function() {

                var url = '{{ url('service') }}' + $(this).val() + '/categories/';

                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    var select = $('form select[name= category_id]');

                    select.empty();

                    $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                        select.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.name + '</option>');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the javascript you're using, please?

Comment: <script>
        $(function() {
            $('select[name=service_id]').change(function() {

                var url = '{{ url('service') }}' + $(this).val() + '/categories/';

                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    var select = $('form select[name= category_id]');

                    select.empty();

                    $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                        select.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.name + '</option>');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: can't add javascript code in this post, bcs too much code wrotten.

Comment: been added to my post

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused as to what you're wanting to achieve, are you wanting to show options which are related to the `$jenisHewan` model?

Comment: yes, so this is a Pet adoption project, JenisHewan as parent and RasHewan ( Animal Race ) as child, JenisHewan have a related with RasHewan model. this is what i want, when i use select option <option value=""> Dog <option> , then i want to show what current related with 'Dog' value

Comment: Ok thanks, now I understand what you need, what part of your code is causing the problem? Does the ajax request to select the animal races work?

Comment: still not work in my view